# Interpolating from a coarse coordinate grid to a fine coordinate grid

Tags: r

I have two data frames. The first (REF) contains daily temperatures (along the columns) from a climate model on 2.5° x 2.5° grids (along the rows) covering the whole globe, and the other (OBS) contains daily temperatures for the same time period on finer 0.5° x 0.5° grids also covering the whole globe.

```
REF    5760 obs. of 9864 variables

X     Y     1979.01.01     1979.01.02     1979.01.03
0.00  40.00 10.50          10.40          11.20
2.50  40.00 9.65           8.45           9.30
5.00  40.00 7.75           10.80          8.80

OBS    61143 obs. of 9864 variables

X     Y     1979.01.01     1979.01.02     1979.01.03
0.00  40.00 9.50           8.60           10.10
0.50  40.00 8.65           8.75           9.70
1.00  40.00 8.75           9.80           8.10
```

I wish to interpolate the daily temperature values from the REF data frame to match the finer spatial resolution of the coordinates from the OBS data frame. My output (REF2) should therefore be a dataframe with the same dimensions as the OBS data frame. I have checked various interp solutions but am getting lost on all this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried the akima package and the bilinear function but I haven't been able to adapt this to my situation